# how to auto format timestamp column while fetching with spring jdbc template?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am using spring jdbc for fetching the data from database, in the following way

```
JdbcTemplate jdbc=new JdbcTemplate(ds);
List<Map<String,Object>> resultSet=jdbc.queryForList(dsDetailsIN.get("query").toString());
```

where ds is the datasource object.

As i am not aware of data types of columns of the resultSet, So the columns with the DATETIME datatypes are converted into java date format. However i want to auto format the data columns if any in appropriate format for date/DateTime/TimeStamp columns.

Comment: So, test if the returned value in the map is a Date, and format it the way you want.

Comment: can you share the code you use for output?

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code using a custom [RowMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) instead of the simple `queryForList()`:

```
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    List<Map<String,Object>> resultSet = 
            //Use a custom RowMapper
            jdbc.query(dsDetailsIN.get("query").toString(), new RowMapper<Map<String,Object>>() {

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            //The map per row
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            //The target date format
            DateFormat nice = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            //Iterating the columns.
            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            for(int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
                Object o = rs.getObject(i);
                //If a date use formatted String instead
                if(o instanceof Date) {
                    o = nice.format(o);
                }
                //put into map.
                map.put(meta.getColumnName(i), o);
            }
            return map;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan, Its worked for me. But in one scenario its conflicting is in case the query itself contains the formatting of the date column. which is in other format

Comment: It's your source - so it's your query as well? So you might just remove the custom formatting from the SQL? Else you'd might want to call a different RowMapper for that specific statement? Or for statements containing some specific string (date convert functions)